# How to not render a Header on landing(Login page) page but always on all other pages in react-router v6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to create a website that has a landing page (Login) without a header, but once the user has logged in, all subsequent pages will have the header.  I have tried the following but the syntax is incorrect and therefore does not work.  Please can someone advise?

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from '..path for landing';
import component1 from '..path for component1';
import component2 from '..path for component2';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Login />} />
        
        <Header />
        
        <Route path="/component1" element={<component1 />} />
        <Route path="/component2" element={<component2 />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can we do this ? `<div>{isLogged && <Header/>}</div>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a layout component that renders the `Header` component and an `Outlet` component for nested routes to be rendered into.

Exmaple:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const AuthLayout = () => {
  // ... perhaps some authentication logic to protect routes?
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Outlet />
    </>
  );
};
```

...

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
        <Route element={<AuthLayout />}>
          <Route path="/component1" element={<component1 />} />
          <Route path="/component2" element={<component2 />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

...

```
<Route exact path="/" element={<Login />} />   
<Route 
        render={({ location }) => ['/', '/login'].includes(location.pathname)
            ? null
            : <Header/>
        }
    />
<Route exact path="/" element={<Login />} />
```

...